# Pass Access Token to API in Node

Tags: node.js

I am learning Node by developing an application that would hit the relevant server and extract its data.
Here, I am stuck as the relevant server demand to pass access token, and I'm not able to extract data successfully.

Here is my code

```
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'any url',
        auth :  {
            accessToken : "token here"
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }
```

But doing this i'm getting error **Error: no auth mechanism defined**

Access token seems to be perfect.

Sorry if this has been asked already but I cannot seem to find a straight answer.

Thanks for your efforts and time.

Comment: Which httpClient are you using? request, fetch; Axios ?

Comment: i am using request as httpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    var req = {
         host: 'YOUR_URL',
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
             Authorization: your token
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
     }
request(req, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body);
    }
```